# Is there a way in a donut Chart.JS to show a % out of 100

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, donut-chart

I have a donut chart showing a number. However is there a way which the donut chart can be out of 100%, so the number I give in the `data` section: say `21`, will show 21% complete out of 100?

Image to show desired outcome:
[image: donut chart]

So the donut ring is greyed out and the coloured section is how much has been completed (or what number we allocate to the `data` section, I've been looking at the documentation and cannot see a way this can be done?

**Code I have currently:**

```
<canvas id="Chart1" style="width=5 height=5"></canvas>
<?php
    $var = 3;
?>

    var ctx = document.getElementById('Chart1').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'doughnut',

    // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ['% Complete'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'chart1',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(102, 178, 255)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(102, 178, 255)',
                // Below I just pull out 1 number from the db
                data: [<?php echo $var ?>] 
            }]
        },
    });
```

My code outputs the below (so the 3 fills up the whole donut), whereas I would like it show 3% out of 100% complete.

[image: chart]

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community. For starters, please include a [mcve] to your question that includes all the code you have so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing data of [3, 97]. You're trying to use it as a loading indicator but it seems designed for showing 100% of things broken into parts.

If you pass simply `[3]`, then that's 100% of your dataset

Answer (score 2):

Create a two value dataset, like:

```
[percent_value, 100-percent_value]
```

Here's a full demo:

```js
const originalDoughnutDraw = Chart.controllers.doughnut.prototype.draw;

Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.doughnut.prototype, {
  draw: function() {
    const chart = this.chart;
    const {
      width,
      height,
      ctx,
      config
    } = chart.chart;

    const {
      datasets
    } = config.data;

    const dataset = datasets[0];
    const datasetData = dataset.data;
    const completed = datasetData[0];
    const text = `${completed}% completed`;
    let x, y, mid;

    originalDoughnutDraw.apply(this, arguments);

    const fontSize = (height / 350).toFixed(2);
    ctx.font = fontSize + "em Lato, sans-serif";
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";


    x = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2);
    y = (height / 1.8) - fontSize;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
    mid = x + ctx.measureText(text).width / 2;
  }
});


var context = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var percent_value = 3;
var chart = new Chart(context, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['Completed', 'Pending'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'First dataset',
      data: [percent_value, 100 - percent_value],
      backgroundColor: ['#00baa6', '#ededed']
    }]
  },
  options: {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, this is fantastic thank you. May I ask would it be easy enough to alter the 3% complete to replace with a PHP variable? May I also ask if this is something new that chartJS offers now as I couldn't find any documentation on doing this on their site?